# Dynamic Thread Pool Management

Tags: java, threadpool, priority-queue

I have three types of Tasks A,B,C to be executed with minimum thresholds in a Thread Pool:

- (A) 70 %
- (B) 20 %
- (C) 10 %

Pool Size: 100 Threads.

How to ensure in any given time the following distribution:

1. No Idle Threads: If ,for example, only type C tasks exists, The pool will be 100% C's
2. No starvation: B and C Tasks will eventually be served

Comment: How may cores do you have?  Unless you have 100+ cores, there is likely to always be enough tasks to keep your cores busy.  Having more threads than cores can be slower for CPU intensive tasks.

Comment: the 100 figure is just for convenience.

Comment: If you make C large enough to use every core, it doesn't matter that other threads are idle (in fast it is better that other threads are idle)

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following strategy:

- maintain a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) with all items inserted into the queue having a priority field which is the basis for comparison. Let tasks of type C have priority 0, B have 10, and A have 20 (lower values == higher priority)
- Maintain a separate 'tracking' queue of active B items in the PriorityBlockingQueue. A separate Timer instance attempts to remove all B items from the PriorityBlockingQueue, when successful it decrements the priority for B and reinserts it into the PriorityBlockingQueue - this ensures no starvation for items of type B. Unsuccessful attempts mean the item has already been processed and that the item should be removed from the tracking queue.
- Threads in the thread pool attempt to pop an element of the queue before working on it.